# I can't seem to get my respond_to block in my controller to send view.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

so, the create action on my model works, but it won't send a the javascript view back to the browser.  I went through my stacktrace and found the problem(i think))

```
    Rendered posts/create.js.erb (51.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1173ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `escape_javaScript' for #<#<Class:0x4924020>:0x491c598>):
    1: $('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javaScript(@post.title) %></h1>").append("<%= escape_javaScript(@post.content) %>");

  app/views/posts/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts_create_js_erb__102872654_38327136'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:45:in `create'

Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (54.0ms)
```

does rails 3.1 not support 'escape_javascript'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports [`escape_javascript`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript) but not `escape_javaScript`. Note capital 'S' in your case.